# Hide a column in HTML to Excel

Tags: php, html, excel

I'm working on an export tool to Excel format. To reduce the generating time, I don't want to use PHPExcel.
This is a part of my code : http://ideone.com/HCleMO

I like to hide the first column A named ID. I tested the following code in my HTML,

CSS :

```
style="display:none"
```

HTML :

```
hidden="hidden"
```

No results with these tests. Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can give all the `th` and `td` a class and then use CSS to `display:none`

Comment: If you don't want to display column A, why even bother writing it? It's only HTML markup that you're creating

Comment: @mark-baker Hiding column it's an option in Excel. On this case I like to use it.

Comment: I think there is an incomprehension on my question. The render in ideone it's not the real render! The PHP headers are skip. If I use PHPExcel I can do it, but I prefers ask the question to find a solution with HTML. If there is solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following:

CSS

```
tr td:first-child{ display:none; }
```

jQuery

```
$("tr td:first-child").hide();
$("tr td").first().hide();
```

or if you dont want to use the psuedocodes `:first-child`, add same class in all first  of each row and hide them using CSS/JS

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. But you can't use JS in Excel write by html. I tested the first but not working like I said in my question.

Answer (score 0):

For tables, you have to perform the same operation on all the elements in the same row/column.  So if you want to hide the first column, give all the elements the same CSS class and then say `style=display:none`